# Symfony 2 DoctrineBehaviors translatable: too many db queries

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, entities

I am using the Translatable trait from [KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable) with the "proxy translations" for my Category entity, so I have a CategoryTranslation entity containing the property "name", when I want to get the list of all my categories I end up with the Symfony debug toolbar telling me the page has run thousands of queries and took over 5 seconds to load.

This is my code:

```
$categories = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('OylexCategoryBundle:Category') 
    ->findAll();

$categoryList = array();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $categoryList[] = array(
        'id' => $category->getId(),
        'name' => $category->getName(),
    );
}

//To output as json
```

You see, the line `'name' => $category->getName(),` is making a new query for each iteration of the foreach loop.

Is there a way to join the translation table so that the "name" property is fetch alongside the category?

I tried this, but it's still doing a query per call:

```
$categories = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('OylexCategoryBundle:Category')
    ->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select(array('c'))
    ->leftJoin('OylexCategoryBundle:CategoryTranslation', 'ct', 'WITH', 'c.id = ct.translatable AND ct.locale = \'en\'')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to join using the mapped field given by the translatable module:

```
->innerJoin('c.translations', 'ct')
```